# unknown error code -24

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, google-play-store, installation

I have Android 4.1.2 on Samsung galaxy S2

I install an app and get this error:

unknown error during appliaction install -24

googling this line should clearing Google play cache might help

but it didn't work for me. Any other solution?

Comment: Why do you need another solution? Doesn't clearing the cache solve the issue? That's the least dangerous thing to do. Of course, a factory-reset might help as well, but that's like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut.

Answer (score 1):

I've just checked that again: "Error -24" in most cases is caused by a failed install/update. To solve it, uninstall the app from your device. After that, you should be able to install it again.